# User not requiring password when switching to it

Tags: 16.04, ftp

I just created a user "gitftp" using `adduser gitftp` and gave it a password, containing lower case letters and numbers, and if I run the command `su gitftp` it just switches to that user rather than asking me to enter a password. If I try to upload files using FTP with that user I get a Login authentication failed Access denied: 530 error. I am trying to upload to the /var/www/test directory and the gitftp user should have permissions

UPDATE: for some reason the user can SFTP to the server but not FTP to the server. It works using FileZilla if I choose SFTP but what I want to use it for is curl and I am not sure how I can use SFTP with curl.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more information: **how** did you create the user? were you in a root shell when you gave the `su gitftp` command? To what directory are you trying to upload files - and what are its ownership and permissions?

Comment: If you switch with `su user` from root it will never ask for a password because root is the privileged user. If you switch from a non-privileged user to another use it should ask though.

Comment: I tried to switch to a different user from root and it asked for the password, although that user was a sudouser

Comment: Being a sudouser doesn't itself provide root privileges, it just means the user *can* become root - by explicit use of `sudo`

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: What's the output of `id -u` before you run `su gitftp` (without `sudo`!)?